# PHP - Open 2 Html Pages

Tags: php, html

I have this problem to solve.

I gonna make an email campaign to my clients with some affiliate promotions.

The email will have some direct links to the promotions that goes through a php script in my site. (ex: http://mysite.com/promo.php?promoId=x)

In this script I will manage my database queries and cookie.

In cases that I detect through the cookie that this user has not made any click in the last x days I would like to present him with two html pages: my main website page and the external site referring to the promo.

How can I do this? I currently use header( "Location: $promo_url" ) to redirect to the promo url... but in same cases stated before I would need two urls to open.

Thanks in advance for all your answers
GS

Answer (score 2):

You could have the script output JavaScript with `window.open` instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open("link1"); // open link1 in a separate window
    window.location.href = "link2"; // point this window to link2
</script>
```

If you can, however, it would be much better to explicitly show the user a link to the second location somewhere on the page instead of forcefully opening another window / tab for them.

Comment: Most people have popup blockers, so this will fail very often.

Comment: This is true, but what's try to be done is promotional content opening in a new window. @G Soares is basically making a popup, so it's to be expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use frames (ugh), an iframe within the main page to display the second page (somewhat less ugh), or use popup windows (truly ugh, and probably not possible due to everyone having popup blockers these days).

Answer (score 1):

Show them your site, and in your site have a hidden `a` link tag, which will link to the affiliate site with the attribute `_blank`. Using jQuery, once the DOM is ready trigger a click event to the hidden link tag.

E.x.
HTML

```
<a id="affiliateLink" href="http://www.affiliatesite.com/asdad" target="_blank" style="display:none;">Visit Affiliate</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#affiliateLink').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's really no good way to do what you want without using iframes (ugh) or popups (double ugh).  The other answers are how to use those techniques, but a possible 'better' solution would be to display a banner on your page when you detect the user hasn't been to your site in a while.  The banner could say something along the lines of `Click here for information about our awesome promotion`, and it'd be easy to make it stand out.  That way, you're not forcing popups (which no one will ever see), and while iframes aren't terrible from a user perspective, they don't really scream "modern web design".